# Why location updates in background mode is slow after iOS 11 update?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ios11

iOS used to wake up my app in background when it was killed, during location updates.

After updating to iOS 11, the "wake up" process takes longer (after the user covered a distance of a mile or 2). I haven't seen any new changes to the location manager documentation which relates to this.

Any one else experiencing the same issue??

Comment: This seems to be a weird thing in iOS 11 release. Location updates take longer and location services take up too much battery power due to that. iOS 10 was stable as a rock. Maybe we may wait for another iOS 11 update to see if this is patched.

Comment: @BadhanGanesh did you find any other online thread related to this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. @Nil